# Set Firebase Functions Security Level From Command Line

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I'm deploying a firebase HTTP function using the command line and would like to change the security-level to 'secure-always' like you can do in the gcloud deploy command:

```
gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME --trigger-http --security-level=secure-always
```

I cannot use the UI to deploy this function (I do not store my source code on source repos), and am in a Firebase functions directory so I cannot use gcloud to deploy. Is there a gcloud command I can use to edit the function's security-level after deployment similar to:

gcloud functions remove-iam-policy-binding

or a way to specify the security-level pre-deployment? For reference I am deploying a  NodeJS Cloud Function and using firebase deploy --only functions:FUNCTION_NAME. My current fallback option is manually examining the headers in the function, as it is the only option described in this docs page available in my situation: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#security_levels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, there's no `gcloud` command to update the Cloud Function's security level from **HTTP** to **HTTPS**. For now, you can only update the Cloud Function's security level by re-deploying the function or edit the function through [Google Cloud Function Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions):

1. Click the prefer **Function**
2. Click **Edit button**
3. At the bottom of **Trigger** title, click the edit button
4. Check or tick the check box of **Require HTTPS** and click **Save** button
5. Click the **Next** button at the bottom of screen and deploy.

Comment: You can also file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests).